# Audio in HTML5: What happens if it fail to load? What is the default timeout? How to implement your own timeout?

Tags: html, html5-audio

For HTML5 audio, are there any timeout? If so, what is the default timeout time?

How do i set my own timeout?

Comment: By timeout, I'm not sure what you mean in this context. Could you elaborate? What's your deliver method? If you're looking to do anything more than say playback and basic stuff than HTML5 Audio isn't your friend and I'd suggest looking into the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) instead.

Comment: Hi @ChrisW.  I was thinking about some rare cases such as when audio couldn't load after 100 seconds, what will happens? Are there any default timeout?

Comment: @man You can set your audio to preload OR you can you can use error handling to  check the [network state](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_networkstate.asp)  or see if there's a [problem](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_error.asp) with the media